# how do i ignore file types in un-ignored folder

Tags: git

I have a folder (***mainRoot***) that contains a complex structure. Except a folder (***sources***) and all it's children folders and files, everything is ignored.

On top of this, it'd like to ignore all files with a certain extension (***.cache***) in the un-ignored folder and all it's children folders and files(**sources**). How can I do so?

```
!.gitignore
mainRoot/*
!mainRoot/sources/
!mainRoot/sources/*
!mainRoot/sources/**/*

#everything is fine till this point. 
#my intuition calls of an ignore like this
#but it doesn't seem to work

mainRoot/sources/*.cache
mainRoot/sources/**/*.cache
```

Comment: Not sure if you've already tried this, but you can have additional `.gitignore`s in subdirectories within your repo. From there relative file name resolution works as it would if that was your current directory.

Comment: I use git as a wrapper sc as I already have a (crappy)  sc that is provided by the project,  which I can't ditch, and I don't intend on providing unrelated items (like a. Gitignore)  to the crappy sc. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The provided example does allow you to ignore all `.cache` items.

```
git init
subl .gitignore #Added supplied .gitignore
mkdir mainRoot
mkdir mainRoot/sources
touch mainRoot/sources/foo.cache
mkdir mainRoot/sources/bar
touch mainRoot/sources/bar/bar.cache
touch mainRoot/sources/bar/keep.me
git add --all
git status
```

This gives:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   mainRoot/sources/bar/keep.me
```

You have probably already added those files to your repo. To get rid of them:

```
git rm mainRoot/sources/*.cache --cached
```

Then commit the changes.

Comment: I think you might be right! Will give this a try on Monday! I didn't know that even though you ignore a certain file type but have committed that file in the past, you still have that file showing as a changed resource!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a folder, then it will ignore it in any folder, so you simply need this in your .gitignore to ignore all files ending with .cache extension:

```
*.cache
```